# Question about "either and neither"

Tags: grammar

Which of these answers is correct?

> Which way did you go the first one or the second one?
>
> A) I went neither way
>
> B) I didn't go either way

Comment: Both are fine grammatically, but A is now rather antiquated. I think it sounds rather unnatural nowadays. The difference sounds (to me) the same as the difference between: A) I read not a book, but a magazine. B) I didn't read a book; I read a magazine. A is old-fashioned and obsolete (or very nearly).

Comment: Neither one is wrong; either one could be used.

Comment: I'd rather say A than B, myself. Or even, "Neither: I went via Timbuktu" (or wherever).

Answer (score 2):

> Both are fine grammatically, but A is now rather antiquated. I think it sounds rather unnatural nowadays.

(A comment from Billy 2 hours ago)

Some words are used much more often than others.  'Neither' is a word that is not used very often.

"Neither here nor there"

It is the difference between formal and informal English.  I think that 'neither' is rather a formal word.

This is a clever formulation of the difference between the two words:

> Neither one is wrong; either one could be used.  (Comment by J.R.)

..

> [neither a borrower nor a lender be](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/25301.html)

..

"You can make a lot of money in this game. Just ask my ex-wives. Both of them are so rich that neither of their husbands work." — [Lee Trevino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Trevino)

..